# How to get the id of surrounding a element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code an I'm trying to determine the id of the a-element:

```
<li>
 <a class="selectTour" id="32">
   <span>Bla</span>

   <div class="margin-top-2"><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: small">Test 22</font></div>

   <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Created</strong>
 </a>
</li>
```

I cannot use an href element for routing because of the used data framework (backbone.js). I've tried to bind a function on the selectTour class an then I tried to get the id via an event listener (btw the selecTour appears n-times):

```
selectTour:function(event) {
            $.mobile.loading("show");
            var tour_id = event.target.id;

            this.router.navigate("tour/" + tour_id, {trigger: true})
        },
```

The problem is that when the user clicks (for example) on the font element (or an other element than the a element) the wrong id is returned. It seems to me this is a standard javascript/jquery question but I can't figure it out and need a push into the right direction.

Comment: Don't you simply want `this.parentNode.parentNode.id` in the font-element's onclick-function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem here is that the user does not always click the font element.

Comment: That is unclear in your question and it's title, you might want to clarify that. You ask the *id of surrounding a element* and your text states you can attach an event on the elements with class  `selectTour` and *when the user clicks on the font element the wrong id is returned*. I'm confused.. ... why not add an onclick-event to anchors with the class 'selectTour' and inside this function use `this.id` ?

Comment: Edited accordingly to make it more clear. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: No problem. But I'm Still confused... why not add an onclick-event to anchors with the class 'selectTour' and inside this function use `this.id` ? Also, by *href element* you mean the anchor's *href property* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your script little bit this way:

```
var tour_id = ($(event.target)[0].id.length) ? $(event.target)[0].id : $(event.target).closest('a.selectTour')[0].id;
```

---

Because your `event.target` element is not always `selectTour` so it does not get you the id of it, so instead as you are using jQuery you can check for the id length if that is available then assign the id of it otherwise if `event.target` is other than `selectTour` then traverse up to the `selectTour` with `.closest()` the get and assign the id to the `var tour_id`.

---

With jQuery's `.attr()`:

```
var tour_id = ($(event.target).attr('id').length) ? $(event.target).attr('id') : $(event.target).closest('a.selectTour').attr('id');
```

Comment: This works as well and seems to be more bulletproof too me. Than Arun's reply - would you agree?

Comment: If you are asking me then i would say yes this has to be.

Comment: This is what I just did. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest `selectTour` element of the click's target then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get its id.

```
selectTour: function (event) {
    $.mobile.loading("show");
    var tour_id = $(event.target).closest('.selectTour').attr('id');

    this.router.navigate("tour/" + tour_id, {
        trigger: true
    })
},
```

---

You can even try `e.currentTarget.id` if the click handler is targeting the `selectTour` element.

- [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)
- [event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

Answer (score 0):

This thing gave me 32 which i think is correct

```
$('.selectTour').bind('click',function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks four your reply but .selectTour appears n-times.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for